# The text in footer wont align properly

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

This is happening right now: [The footer text is weirdly aligned (text-align is on center here, text-align left puts it slightly left of the center and text-align right works properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VNcf.png)

[I also tried display: table-cell which aligns my text properly but puts the footer itself in an awkward spot and it cant be moved using margins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMTup.png)

Here's my (related) code:

```css
.footer {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 30px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer stuff</h2>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Hopefully this is all you need I prefer to keep my post as short as possible, tell me if you need more and thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: My entire code

```css
Body {
    background-color: darkred;     
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: darkblue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#navbar li {
    float: left;
}
#navbar li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 160px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.container {
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%; /* BE ADVISED! (????) */
}
#ipsumpic1 {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
}
#ipsumpic2 {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}
#sidebarleft {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 1000px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: -350px;
}
#sidebarright {
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 240px;
    float: right;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    background-color: aqua;
    margin-top: -537px;
    margin-right: 1100px;
}
.footer {
    display: table;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 5px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 30px;
    line-height: 12px;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Prachtige website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="Stylesheet"type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type=text/javascript src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.svg" width="200"></a>
            </div>
        </header>
            <ul id="navbar"> 
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="producten.html">Producten</a></li>
                <li><a href="diensten.html">Diensten</a></li>
                <li><a href="over.html">Over Ons</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        <div class="container">
            <main>
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
                <img id="ipsumpic1" src="img/ipsum1.svg">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a pulvinar dolor, a rutrum tortor. Vestibulum auctor finibus odio id efficitur. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur ullamcorper risus neque, sed vehicula augue finibus sed. Donec pretium ornare libero a venenatis. Donec sed ex id tellus posuere interdum. Nullam tincidunt egestas odio non gravida. Sed ut felis aliquet eros commodo elementum. Aliquam ullamcorper, diam quis aliquet tempor, magna nisi laoreet nisl, at vestibulum arcu enim quis elit. </p>
                <img id="ipsumpic2" src="img/ipsum2.svg">
                <p>Ut faucibus dui lectus, vitae pharetra magna maximus quis. Donec sollicitudin sem non ornare vulputate. Suspendisse pretium lacus nec gravida tristique. Sed sed nibh et eros facilisis accumsan. Nam mi elit, fermentum eu laoreet vel, venenatis sit amet leo. Curabitur erat arcu, dictum eu massa quis, hendrerit mattis turpis. Etiam ultrices quam dolor, a interdum erat eleifend eu. Cras sed blandit nunc. In dictum dignissim enim, vel gravida nisl sagittis pellentesque. Quisque fermentum pellentesque velit a faucibus. Nulla facilisi. In fermentum, mi id feugiat ultricies, nulla lorem elementum felis, et pretium velit mauris sit amet odio. Curabitur facilisis, mi in eleifend commodo, enim ex dignissim quam, ut pulvinar magna nisl et orci. Duis pulvinar imperdiet pretium. Nullam vehicula tortor in ex volutpat egestas. </p>
            </main>
            <div id="sidebarleft">
                <aside>
                    <h2>Nieuw nieuws!</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit leo, finibus sed risus eget, semper molestie lacus. Integer dictum laoreet erat a facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum luctus diam a est accumsan, eget maximus sem bibendum. Pellentesque efficitur tellus maximus elit egestas bibendum. Cras efficitur enim tortor, a fringilla lacus tristique quis. Pellentesque neque felis, faucibus nec nibh vel, dapibus congue lorem. Sed scelerisque ligula vitae convallis condimentum. Nulla a ante pulvinar, tristique turpis a, sagittis ipsum. Aliquam fringilla convallis justo, eu eleifend quam placerat ac. Fusce sit amet turpis id lacus consectetur sollicitudin. </p>
                </aside>
            </div>
            <div id="sidebarright">
                <aside>
                    <h2>Social media!</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed velit leo, finibus sed risus eget, semper molestie lacus. Integer dictum laoreet erat a facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum luctus diam a est accumsan, eget maximus sem bibendum. Pellentesque efficitur tellus maximus elit egestas bibendum. Cras efficitur enim tortor, a fringilla lacus tristique quis. Pellentesque neque felis, faucibus nec nibh vel, dapibus congue lorem. Sed scelerisque ligula vitae convallis condimentum. Nulla a ante pulvinar, tristique turpis a, sagittis ipsum. Aliquam fringilla convallis justo, eu eleifend quam placerat ac. Fusce sit amet turpis id lacus consectetur sollicitudin.</p>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="footer">
                <h2>Footer stuff</h2>
            </div>
        </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe the width of 1000px does not completely fit in the display area, so the center of 1000 is not the center of the maybe 700 visible px?

Answer (score 1):

Apply table to parent (`.footer`) and table-cell to children (`.footer h2`)

```css
.footer {
  display: table;
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}

.footer h2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer stuff</h2>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: your code gives me this: https://i.imgur.com/ix4lz1k.png Adding the margins in my code gives me what I talked about in my edit of my post.

Comment: It seems that you are keeping <footer> in some other parent div thats the reason it is not covering the entire width and about the margin you can use according to your requirement

Comment: It would be better if you update your entire code in question

Comment: Added the rest of the code to my post itself for visibility

Answer (score 0):

Solution with flexboxes:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row;
justify-content: center; --> centering horizontally
align-items: center; --> centering vertically
```

if you use table-cell try:

```
vertical-align: center;
```

Comment: the solution with flexboxes does the same as display: table; does (see postedit) and the vertical align with table cell changes nothing from table cell w/o vertical align.